# "get-childitem * -recurse" drops first-level directories

Tags: powershell

Suppose we have the following directory structure:

```
~dir00
   |-> dir10
   |     |-> dir20
   |           |-> file1.txt
   |-> dir11
         |-> file2.txt
```

Now, suppose ~dir00 is the current directory.  I would have expected the two commands 
`get-childitem * -recurse`
and
`get-childitem -recurse`
to produce the same results.  However, they do not.  The behaviour of the second is what I would expect.

I am trying to write a small library of tools for use with our scripted processes.  One tool I need to write is a tool to copy and backup sets of files.  I get, as inputs, something that tells me what files/directories/etc. to copy.  I have no way of knowing what the user may provide.  They may provide a wild-card such as "*", they may provide a file name, they may provide the -recurse parameter, etc. etc.  The inputs are fed to get-childitem.  The inconsistency of the behaviour of get-childitem when the "path" is just "*" is a big problem.  Why does get-childitem suddenly drop the first-level directories when fed a -path of "*" and the -recurse option?  (Note that it only drops the first-level directories.)  **Is there any way I can prevent this odd behaviour?**

Now, it gets more bizzare.  If we put a file in the root directory, so the file structure becomes

```
~dir00
   |-> dir10
   |     |-> dir20
   |           |-> file1.txt
   |-> dir11
   |     |-> file2.txt
   |-> file3.txt
```

then the directories are suddenly NOT dropped.  To reproduce this, just execute the following script:

```
cd $Env:temp
mkdir dir00\dir10\dir20 | out-null
cd dir00
mkdir dir11 | out-null
echo 'hello world 1'>dir10\dir20\file1.txt
echo 'hello world 2'>dir11\file2.txt
$list1 = get-childitem -recurse
echo 'Results of get-childitem -recurse: '
$list1
echo ''
echo 'Number of items:'
$list1.length
echo ''
$list2 = get-childitem * -recurse
echo 'Results of get-childitem * -recurse: '
$list2
echo ''
echo 'Number of items:'
$list2.length
echo ''
echo "hello world 3">file3.txt
$list3 = get-childitem * -recurse
echo 'Results of get-childitem * -recurse: '
$list3
echo ''
echo 'Number of items:'
$list3.length
echo ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround to this anomalous behaviour would be to substitute the asterisk for a period thereby instructing the Get-ChildItem CMDLet to work with the current directory.  Something like this:

```
$suppliedPath = "*"
if($suppliedPath -eq "*"){
    $suppliedPath = $suppliedPath.replace("*", ".")
}
Get-ChildItem $suppliedPath -recurse
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am already doing, but that is a hack, and it's not clear in what other situations a similar problem may crop up.  I am looking/hoping for the existence of some option or flag I can set in get-childitem that will force it to include the first-level directories.  Thanks for taking the time to respond though.

Comment: There isn't a flag you can set; the examples on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) for Get-ChildItem describe the expected functionality of using (*) as wildcard.  Your scenario isn't explicitly covered but I think it's reasonable to imply from the information that is supplied that the behaviour you are experiencing is not as intended.  Perhaps file a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell)?

Comment: Done: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/812178/get-childitem-sometimes-drops-first-level-directories

Answer (score 8):

This is because the path that you are feeding into Get-ChildItem is different.

When you execute:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

You are saying the same as:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse
```

Or interpreted as: Get Child Item -Path starts at the current directory (dir00)

When you execute:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse
```

You are saying, with the *, iterate through all items in the directory, feed those paths to Get-ChildItme, and then Recurse through those items. So the equivalent command that is executed is this:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem *
Get-ChildItem $items -Recurse
```

Which works out to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ./dir10 -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Path ./dir11 -Recurse
```

Now, what you are seeing is an odd exception (or could be seen as a bug) to this behaviour, and it only happens in this case when you have a root directory that only contains folders and no files. If you create one file in the dir00:

```
echo 'hello world 1'>test1.txt
```

And then we execute

```
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse
```

It lists exactly the same as `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`. So you will only get different results only when you have root directories with no files, only folders.

Comment: This sounds right, good answer; it's worth noting that the DOS dir command interprets this input differently in that it does return everything including the first level directories (cmd /c dir * /s).

Comment: I agree that this does seem quite odd, possibly a bug.

Comment: Woops. Just noticed your final comment is exactly the edits I just made to my question. Almost makes sense, except why do the first level directories suddenly get added back in when you have files in the base directory?  the behaviour is very inconsistent and makes programming arount it next to impossible.